# 'canAuthenticate()' está en desuso en android

Tags: java, android-studio, autenticación, android-biometrico

estoy actualizando para que funcione la autenticacion biometrica, ya que 'canAuthenticate()' me aparece depreciado, pero he tenido un problema que no encuentro como actualizar. Ya que me marca error al crear una instancia de BiometricManager.
En el from me marca error de que no se puede resolver el metodo

```
BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this);
       switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)) {
           case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
               Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.");
               break;
           case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
               Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.");
               break;
           case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:
               Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.");
               break;
           case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:
               // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
               final Intent enrollIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL);
               enrollIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
                       BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL);
               startActivityForResult(enrollIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
               break;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega la dependencia en tu archivo `build.gradle` :

```
   // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"
```

Asegura usar la nueva clase de AndroidX, este podría ser el problema principal por el cual no puedes usar el método `BiometricManager.from(..)`:

```
//import android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricManager;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager;
```

de esta forma podrás usar tu código sin problemas:

```
   BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this);
    switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG | BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)) {
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
            Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.");
            break;
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
            Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.");
            break;
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:
            Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.");
            break;
        case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:
            // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
            final Intent enrollIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL);
            enrollIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
                    BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG | BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL);
            startActivityForResult(enrollIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
    }
```